# Adding multiple ints to one vector index? 'Cout' not working

Tags: c++, vector

So I found this code on here that I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Something{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    vector <Something> v;
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;

    Something temp;
    temp.x = x;
    temp.y = y;
    v.push_back(temp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << endl; // Error: No operator "<<" matches these operands. Operand types are std::ostream << Something
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get multiple ints into one vector index. 
`cout` is not working when I try to print the contents of the vector.

First of all, am I even doing this multiple int thing right? I'm relatively new to C++.

And if I am doing this right, any ideas as to why `cout` isn't working? 
I also tried `v.push_back({x,y})` and that didn't work. Any idea what is going on with `cout`? Thanks a lot.

---

**EDIT**:
Thank you very much so far. I just have one more question. If I were to modify my code to take multiple inputs and later wanted everything in the vector sorted according to "y" from largest to smallest.

Example (Original Vector Contents (x,y))

`12 4
 1  2
 4  10
 1  1
 1  2`

Sorted according to 'y' (largest to smallest)

`4  10
 12 4
 1  2
 1  2
 1  1`

I know how to do a regular sort but not one according to the second number (y). How do I do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the error says, there's no overloaded `operator<<` function declared for your structure.

There are three possible solutions: The first is to output each member of the structure, like

```
std::cout << v[i].x << ' ' << v[i].y << '\n';
```

The other is to create a function that does the above, either as a member function or as a non-member function.

The third solution is to create an overloaded `operator<<` function for the structure:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Something const& something)
{
    return os << something.x << ' ' something.y;
}
```

---

I recommend you [find a good beginners book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read the chapters about output, structures and classes, and operators and operator overloading.

Comment: Thank you very much so far. I just have one more question however, it doesn't look good when I write it here (formatting) so I've put it in my question as an edit. Thanks again.

Comment: @G_Man Read about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). It can take a comparison function argument, that can compare anything you want. Or you could specialize [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) for your structure and use `std::greater` as the comparator when calling `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

cout does not work for your struct because it was not defined to do so.
I think you can find the answer here. 
[Overloading operators in typedef structs (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047191/overloading-operators-in-typedef-structs-c)

Answer (score 0):

`operator<<` is not automatically available between `cout` and objects of user defined classes. They need to be defined before you can be used.

In your case, you need to define a friend function inside the struct  definition's body

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Something const& s);
```

to be able to use

```
cout << v[i] << endl;
```

The implementation of the function is not too difficult.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Something const& s)
{
    return out << s.x << " " << s.y;
}
```

If you want be able to use:

```
Something s;
std::cin >> s;
```

you'll have to define a similar function.

Comment: Thank you very much so far. I just have one more question however, it doesn't look good when I write it here (formatting) so I've put it in my question as an edit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<<` is an operator. It is defined on `std::cout` (which is an `std::ostream`) for a number of types. For example, it's defined for `int`, which is why this works:

```
std::cout << 3;
```

However, you are trying to apply the `operator<<` to your own `Something` class, but it has no such operator definition. You can add it like this:

```
struct Something {
    // Other stuff here
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Something const& smth) ;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Something const& smth) {
    os << "(" << smth.x << ", " << smth.y << ")";
    return os;
}
```

Then your code should work. Overloading this operator is actually more difficult than overloading others because you need to understand what `friend` does.

**Edit:**

`friend` is actually not needed in your case, because `x` and `y` are public. But in the general case you need it to be able to print private members of your class.

**Edit 2:**

To make the previous edit clear, you can omit the entire in-struct declaration of the operator, since it will be looked up globally. You only need it (and then it needs to be `friend`ly) if the operator needs to read private members.

Comment: Actually, when the compiler sees an expression like `cout << s`, it invokes _global function_ `operator<<`, so you do need to declare it as a `friend` inside the class of `Something` :)

Comment: Thank you all very much so far. I just have one more question however, it doesn't look good when I write it here (formatting) so I've put it in my question as an edit. Thanks again.

Comment: The `friend` declarations do have the right to access the non-public (and public) members of the class; However, you declare the method as a `friend` because it needs to be a function (which needs to be defined outside the class's scope) and yet has the access to the members since the compiler invokes it as a _global function_ :)

Comment: @someOne My second edit was to make it clear that you do not need to declare it inside of the class *at all* if you don't need private members. It can be just defined outside of the function. I.e. this works: http://ideone.com/cTOE48